# ESLint issue in the importing firebase in React app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, eslint

I have two imports at the beginning of my file:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "***",
  databaseURL: "***",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "***",
  messagingSenderId: "***",
  appId: "***",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

but i get ESLint error:
`Line 1:1: 'firebase/app' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S firebase/app' to add it import/no-extraneous-dependencies`
`Line 2:1:  'firebase/database' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S firebase/database' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies`

I already have firebase dependencies:
`dependencies: { "firebase": "^8.4.1"}`
and without ESLint it works correctly.

Applied this solution, but it did not help unfortunately:

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {
   "devDependencies": true}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out two solutions.Either one will solve the problem.

1. Now to use database from firebase it is enough to write in jsx file simply:

   import firebase from "firebase";
2. To add to the eslint json file:

   ```
   "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
       "warn", {
           "bundledDependencies": false
       }
   ]
   ```

I would like to point out that instead of "error" it should be written either "off" or "warn".

Answer (score 0):

If you update `eslint-plugin-import` to v2.23.4, you may find this error is fixed. There was a recent regression in the package resolution algorithm.

```sh
npm update eslint-plugin-import
```

[Read more about the issue](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/pull/2097)